# Performance issues in AngularJS 1.0.7 and angular-translate

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I have serious performance issues when my angularjs 1.0.7 webapp loads for first time all translation files with angular-translate.
The point is we have only one huge translation file for each language. At the moment with more than 3000 translation lines each. So, if you debug the loading times it takes up to 3 or 4 seconds to load.

I have made some tests and noticed if we use small files with a few translations the performance improves.

I have read a bit about angular-translate and I see there is some partial loading feature, that can load one translation file per each view which maybe is a better approach. I have also read about namespaces that maybe improve performance too.

However, I don´t know if this functionality is working with my angularjs 1.0.7 version because I don´t see anything in the angular-translate docs. I would like to confirm which is the latest angular-translate version that is compatible with my angularjs app and check if there is a feature that can fix this problem.

To migrate angularjs is not an option at this moment.

Do you think it´s possible to use partial files with this angular version, or otherwise is there any other approach to improve this performance issue?

Comment: which angular-translate version do you use?

Comment: New answer: 1.1.1

Comment: I have just found out that in angular-translate-loader-partial github I can see compatibilities in the bower.js file. So, angular-translate-loader-partial version 0.2.2 is compatible with angular-translate 1.1.1 and angularjs 1.0.8 hopefully same that 1.0.7. I will check if this version works. But apart from compatibility, do you think this is the right approach to fix the performance problems?

Comment: Sure, with the partial loader you can create a translation file for each view and only load the file if the user navigates to the view. But i heard the partial loader was quite buggy and still is thought i got it to work just fine in the newest version.
Anyway i really suggest that you update your angular version. Beside the huge performance improvements there are a lot of security fixes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I know, but it´s not a trivial migration and at the moment it´s not possible. I have done some test with partial loading and at the moment it´s working. Let´s cross fingers. Thanks.